# date command read file info like stat

Tags: bash

I found this is a script that seems to read in the date. It sort of works like the stat command. I had no idea date could do this. 
I have no idea how it works, and do not see the '-I' or '-r' flag in the man pages.

```
/bin/date -I -r /home/capser/casper_file.20180813.csv
2018-08-13
```

Can someone point me to the documentation.

Comment: I bet you get the same date if you simply use `ls -l /home/capser/casper_file.20180813.csv`. `date -I -r` is simply returning the last modification time for your file, it's not parsing anything from the filename itself. If you want to parse the `20180813` from the filename, look at `awk` (with `-F.` and `{print $2}`) or `sed` or simply read the filename into a variable and use bash parameter expansion with substring removal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date` is provided by your operating system; it is not part of bash itself, and which options it provides varies based on your OS: The local documentation provided by `man date` is canonical in terms of determining which options are available for the version of `date` you actually have installed.

With respect to documentation for the version of `date` the command you're quoting was written for, however -- those options are provided by GNU `date`; a copy of its man page is available at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html, and reads in part as follows:

> ```
>    -r, --reference=FILE
>         display the last modification time of FILE
>
>    -I[FMT], --iso-8601[=FMT]
>           output date/time in ISO 8601 format.  FMT='date' for date only
>           (the default), 'hours', 'minutes', 'seconds', or 'ns' for date
>           and time to the indicated precision.  Example:
>           2006-08-14T02:34:56-06:00
> ```

---

If you want to know how to find the modification time of a file on a non-GNU system, that's a different question -- for which [BashFAQ #87](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/087) is likely to be helpful.